# Run perl script from batch file

Tags: perl, batch-file

I'd like to run my perl script every 2 mins. So I decide to use task scheduler to call batch file that can invoke the perl script. The problem is that the perl script file can only be executed on server linux62. So how can i create the batch file to call the perl script? Thanks.

Comment: So, What you have tried ?

Comment: You have a perl script that runs on linux, that you want to run on Windows via a batch file?

Comment: Yes. The perl script will not return anything or need any input parameters. I just want to call it through batch file on Windows. I tried to use ssh to switch to linux server and run perl command. However, it did not work properly for me.

Comment: "Did not work properly" is not a problem description. And why don't you simply schedule the program on the linux server?

Comment: From the Linux box: `crontab -e`

Comment: A program on the Linux box can be run by using SSH. There are many SSH kits around. SSH is available in Cygwin. Alternatively, the PuTTY kit has plink.exe which can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed perl on your windows system? so that you can run perl in windows platform.
If not installed You can install the perl using cygwin or by using the strawberry perl. 
steps for installing through Cygwin *http://slu.livejournal.com/17395.html*
After installing the perl you need to set the environmental variables and hence you can do call the perl using the batch file.

Comment: What part of Perl would you use to run something on another machine?

Comment: @Liturgist I can use SSH or Telnet to run something on another machine. Since I couldn't able to comment for that question I used answer option since I don't have enough reputation